# Area shared layout _ViewStart.cthml

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

i have a multiple area and i want to point my layout in my share area folder. 
my folder is

```
App
 -...
 -Model
   -...
 -Controller
   -...
 -View
    |-Shared
       - _layout.cshtml <--- root layout
       - _layout2.cshtml <--- workaround 
    - _ViewStart.cshtml <--- OK!
 -Areas
  |-Areaname1
    |-Controllers
    |-Views
      |-Shared
        - _layout.cshtml <--- my area layout
      - _ViewStart.cshtml <--- i want to use the layout above
  |-Areaname2
    -...
```

code inside my `Areas` `Views/` `_ViewStart.chtml`

```
@{
// Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; <--- will point on the root layout
// Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml"; <--- view to root
// Layout = "~Area/Areaname1/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; <--- correct path
// Layout = "~/Areaname1/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; <--- same error above
}
```

Point a layout to an area.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the standard view engine? Per default it should prefer the Views of your current area.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt thank you for your reply. yes its a fresh mvc 5 app.

Comment: Could you explain (in words) what problem you workaround is solving (compared to no workaround)? I am not exact sure, what you are asking here.

Comment: i didnt actually do anything in my workaround. the problem is the routing of the actual folder is located.the layout by default it is pointing to the root view folder globally and not it the area regardless where is your _viewstart.cshtml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; <--- will point on the root layout
}
```

You explicit say, look in the root (`~`) and use `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

You probably want to use:

```
@{
     Layout = "_layout.cshtml";
}
```

This first looks in your area folder, and if it does not find any `_layout.cshtml` there, it will look in the `~/Views/Shared/` folder.

You can set the lookup path in the `RazorViewEngine` or register some customs to it. [See the source code](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs#L17) for example.

Per default they are:

- "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
- "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
- "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
- "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
- "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
- "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
- "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
- "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"

Where:

- 2 = Area
- 1 = Controller
- 0 = Action/View (`_layout` for example)

Comment: `Layout = "_layout.cshtml";` will get me a `System.Web.HttpException: 'The layout page "_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/Areas/AreaName1/Views/_Layout.cshtml".'`

Comment: Could it be, that by chance `_Layout.cshtml` includes another `_Layout.cshtml`? In that case, use a full path in your sub layout, e.g. `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` @JuliusLimson